# How to save geospatial point data using spring data neo4j version 4.1.2

Tags: java, spring-data, geospatial, spring-data-neo4j

How to save geospatial point data using spring data neo4j version 4.1.2,

I could not find example There are few example but seem all depcricated. Quick help really appreciated.